# Direct database connection on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI)

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I got a free **Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI)** service from Oracle for two months.
I would like to create an Oracle database and connect to it directly over the internet (I don't want to create a VPN tunnel).

Do you know how I should do it?

Comment: I recommend to use Autonomous. Autonomous database can be accessed directly from internet, if you configure that way https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/network-access-change-topublic.html

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, use this URL pattern:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:/@OCI_DB_NAME_high?TNS_ADMIN=PATH_TO_THE_WALLET_FOLDER
```

user name and password as usual, the Wallet should be unzipped.

```
Properties info = new Properties();     
info.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_USER_NAME, DB_USER);
info.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_PASSWORD, DB_PASSWORD);          
... 

OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
ods.setURL(DB_URL);    
ods.setConnectionProperties(info);

OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection) ods.getConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself.

To get to the database server without configuring a VPN link, you can create a virtual machine accessible via an external IP address and ssh from it to a local address from the 10.0.0.0 network

Comment: You can also put the IP address of any machine in the firewall of your Cloud account, and access from there… including your home computer… at least you will have GUI tools at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Spring Boot sample to connect to OCI managed autonomous database.

https://github.com/oracle-devrel/oci-sdk-java-samples/tree/main/usecases/connect-autonomous-database

Answer (score 0):

You can also use OCI Bastion servers to connect to a cloud database on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI) directly over the internet. OCI Bastion servers provides restricted and time-limited access to target resources that don't have public endpoints. Bastions let authorized users connect from specific IP addresses to target resources using Secure Shell (SSH) sessions. When connected, users can interact with the target resource by using any software or protocol supported by SSH.

Targets can include resources like compute instances , DB systems (Oracle Base Database Service, Exadata Database Service, Autonomous Database)

Before creating the Bastion Session in OCI Console you need to prepare the following:

1. The VCN (Virtual Cloud Network) that the target resource was created in
2. The Private Subnet that the target resource was created in
3. The Private IP of the Host of the Cloud Database Instance
4. The Connect String Service Name of the target Pluggable Database
5. The IP address from which you plan to connect, to sessions hosted by the bastion

Here's a link to a how-to guide on how to connect to an oracle cloud database instance using Oracle Base Database Service (previously named as dbcs)  in a private network. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bJ3JlpGlPo&list=PLdtXkK5KBY56jDbMevAMIbZGVAGUz9aYQ&index=14

This demo shows how to create a bastion session, and using ssh port forwarding to connect your local DB tools (on-premises SQL Developer tool) to cloud database instance using DB listener port for sqlnet.